# UxBoolConvert in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm  doing a cart app i need to change the image in the addToCart button 
I have"+" button in list view while i add an item in to cart the image must change to"-". when i delete an item from my cart the image again change to"+".I hope here also i need i notify but how to implement here .I have a Boolean property now. My logic is this "change the Boolean value while adding and removing but i don't know how to change the image to the button" 
 this is my view model

```
public BaseViewModel(){
        App.Instance.ViewModel = this;
        TempList = TempList ?? new ObservableCollection<cm_items>();
        this.Title = AppResources.AppResource.Cart_menu_title;
        this.IsContain = CartCell.buttonImg();
        TempList.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>{
            this.Price = CartCell.Calculate_price();};}
```

and my property

```
  private bool _isContain;
    public bool IsContain
    {
        get { return _isContain; }
        set {_isContain=value;OnPropertyChanged("IsContain");}
    }
```

and converter

```
 public class BoolToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
      #region IValueConverter implementation

    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)  {

            if((bool)value == true)
    return "add.png";
    else
    return "minus.png";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

but still i have no image in the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my view cell

```
  var addedOrNotImageBinding = new Binding("IsAddedToCart", 0, new ImagePathConvertor());
        btn_Cart.SetBinding(ImageButton.SourceProperty,addedOrNotImageBinding);

        btn_Cart.Clicked += (sender, e ) =>
            {
                sender = BindingContext;

                cm_items item = (cm_items)sender;
                //ViewCell viewCell = (ViewCell)sender;
                //BaseViewModel item = (BaseViewModel)viewCell.BindingContext;
                if (item.IsAddedToCart)
                {

                   item.IsAddedToCart = false;
                    App.Instance.ViewModel.TempList.Remove(BindingContext as cm_items);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.IsAddedToCart = true;
                    App.Instance.ViewModel.TempList.Add(BindingContext as cm_items);
                }

             //   CartCell.Calculate_price();
            };
```

and have to add a class named ImagePathConvertor used to convert the image

```
public class ImagePathConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public ImagePathConvertor() { }



    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
        {
            return "minus";
        }
        else
        {
            return "add";
        }


    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and in my model

```
   private bool isAddedToCart;
    public bool IsAddedToCart
    {
        get { return isAddedToCart; }
        set
        {
            isAddedToCart = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsAddedToCart");
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

it works nicely for me image is changing thanks @David

Answer (score 2):

You should bind those properties, not just assign them: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

```
yourImageView.SetBinding<YourViewModelType>(Image.SourceProperty, v => v.IsContain);
```

and remember to set Page `BindingContext` to you ViewModel instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ValueConvertor why not just have a Image property that you bind the image property of the button to.

Put a sample set of code together as follows.

IE

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> listToWatch = new ObservableCollection<string> ();
        public MyPage ()
        {
            Button buttonToUpdate = new Button {Text = "Image Button",  Image = "icon.png"};
            Button UpdatesList = new Button {Text="Add Item to list"};
            buttonToUpdate.SetBinding (Button.ImageProperty, new Binding("ImagePath"));
            UpdatesList.Clicked += (sender,e) => {
                listToWatch.Add (DateTime.Now.ToString());
            };
            listToWatch.CollectionChanged+=(sender,e)=>{
                if( listToWatch.Count%2==1)
                {
                    ImagePath="noci.png";       
                }
                else
                {
                    ImagePath="icon.png";
                }
            };
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    buttonToUpdate,
                    UpdatesList
                }
            };
            Content.BindingContext = this;
        }
        private string imagePath="icon.png";
        public string ImagePath {
            get { return imagePath; } 
            set { 
            imagePath = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged ("ImagePath");
            }
        }
    }
```

I threw the full app up over at
https://github.com/DavidStrickland0/Xamarin-Forms-Samples.git

Comment: @Jauhenka here is my button code which in a view cell

Comment: btn_Cart = new ImageButton
            {

                Source = image1,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            btn_Cart.SetBinding(ImageButton.SourceProperty, "IsContain", BindingMode.Default, new BoolToImageConverter());

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel seems good. Could you provide your button please? How do you bind the IsContain property to your button's Image property?

On your place I'd create a little bit different converter:

```
    public class UxBoolConvertExtension : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
{
    public object OnTrue { get; set; }

    public object OnFalse { get; set; }

    public object OnNull { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ImageSourceHelper.ToImageSourceIfPossible(this.ConvertValue(value), targetType);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    private object ConvertValue(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return this.OnNull;
        return (bool)value ? this.OnTrue : this.OnFalse;
    }
}
```

And would bind button image on your value with a converter like

```
<Button Image="{Binding Icon, Converter={m:UxBoolConvert OnTrue='minus.png', OnFalse='add.png'}}" />
```

Comment: iam not using xaml but C# , my logic is while adding the item to the cart change the IS Contain property to false and change the image name also while deleting the item from cart again the is contain property changes true again it will get true. "How do you bind the IsContain property to your button's Image property?" some of my frnds in xamarin forms help me for that i will put the link of the discussion  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/155886#Comment_155886

Comment: Well, what I see is supposed to work except one thing. Why do you use ImageButton.SourceProperty instead of Button.ImageProperty? Is this also a bindable property?